# Absurd differential in first order condition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, economics

I have derived the following first order condition

$$g(x,C'(x),..)=1,$$

where $x$ is the production level and $C(x)$ the cost of $x$, and $C'(x)$
is the first derivative of $C(x)$ (i.e. the marginal cost). By the implicit function theorem, we can derive how production changes with marginal cost:

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial C'(x)}=-\frac{\partial g/\partial C'(x)}{\partial g/\partial x}$$

Where, the numerator on the RHS equals

$$\partial g/\partial C'(x)=\frac{\partial g/\partial x}{d C'(x)}$$

This then allows us to simplify the second equation

$$-\frac{\frac{\partial g/\partial x}{d C'(x)}}{\partial g/\partial x}=-\frac{1}{C''(x)}$$

And we then conclude that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial C'(x)}=-\frac{1}{C''(x)}$. This is clearly absurd, since with a concave cost function, the derivative of $x$ with respect to marginal cost will always be positive (i.e. production is increasing in marginal cost). What mistake did I make to derive something this absurd?

---

The step I think may be problematic is the third equation $$\partial g/\partial C'(x)=\frac{\partial g/\partial x}{d C'(x)}.$$ I asked about this [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615360/differentiating-a-gx-with-respect-to-a-function-fx?noredirect=1#comment5401498_2615360), and the step seemed fine to some.

Comment: I don't think $\partial x / \partial C'(x)$ makes sense by any convention I'm aware of for interpreting the symbols. Recall that weird notation like $\partial g / \partial C'(x)$ is meant to be read as "the derivative of $g$ in its second place", and that reading is meant to be inferred from the fact that $g$ is being used as shorthand for $g(x, C'(x), \ldots)$, and $C'(x)$ is the formula appearing in the second plane.

Comment: What are the arguments of $g(.)$?  Normally the arguments of a production function are the inputs of factors of production..  For example $f(K,L)=1$ is one way of defining the unit isoquant.  If you're defining a cost function, then $C(q,w,r)$ would be the minimum cost of producing $q$ units of output when factor prices are $w$ and $r$.  Please clarify what you're writing down.

Comment: @EricFisher $g()$ is the function that specifies the first order condition for profit maximisation. Here $C(x)$ is some function that defines the cost of producing $x$ units.

Comment: Are factor prices considered fixed?

Comment: @EricFisher not necessarily. Cost is simply given by  some arbitrary function $C: \mathbb{R_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for your comment. Not sure if I agree that the derivative makes no sense. I believe it makes mathematical sense. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954073/derivative-of-a-function-with-respect-to-another-function

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Here's a simple example.  Let the production function be $Q=2L$.  Let wages be given as $w$.  Then the cost function is $C(q;w)=2wq$.  So marginal cost is $2w$.  In this case, what's your $g(.)$?

Comment: I think the foc would be $2/2w=1$.  But an example for which a FOC might not work does not show that my FOC is nonsensical.

Comment: @pafnuti: The post you link is about differentials, which are much better behaved algebraically than the usual notation for partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from assuming that the cost function is concave.

With perfectly competitive markets, the firm’s profit maximisation problem cannot be solved using first-order conditions. With concave costs, the second derivative of the profit function will be convex, so you can’t solve it via first-order conditions. Attempting to do so gives you a solution that *minimises* profits. (This might also explain your nonsensical result.)

Perhaps you intended to assume that production costs are *convex*. This would give you the intuitive result that output is decreasing in marginal cost.